# License not specified even though there is a LICENSE.md in the README

Tags: github, readme

[image: License not specified]

I have added the LICENSE.md file in the repo but it is still showing up as not specified in the README. 
When I click on license icon in the README, it redirects me to this [Link](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/cd01ac0d4e816686ac20f09bb93cd1d62a1e90362378d51922cfd11c6f6fe261/68747470733a2f2f696d672e736869656c64732e696f2f6769746875622f6c6963656e73652f616268696e61762d756a6a6177616c2f436f64696e672d426c6f672d7573696e672d426f6f7473747261703f636f6c6f723d353642454238). This is expected as I have added the MIT license but why isn't it showing up in the README? 
[Link to repo](https://github.com/Abhinav-Ujjawal/Coding-Blog-using-Bootstrap)

I tried to remove this line in the README and then added it again as two separate commits. But it didn't work.

Comment: It shows MIT for me. Can you try opening the repo in incognito mode?

Comment: @subodhkalika Thanks for the quick response. It has been updated for me as well now (without any change in the code). I am not sure why this was happening though.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized this after submitting the answer, the README somehow updated itself, and the issue has been resolved without any action from my side.

If someone else is facing something similar, you can try giving it some time, and it will most likely update itself. In my case, the issue persisted for around three hours. This was perhaps some glitch or caching issue on the platform.